# Which Frame of Reference is Correct?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, covariance

I am reading a lot about the theory of special relativity, but I have a very basic question about this theory I still don't understand. Consider a particle in two inertial reference frames $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$. The reference frame $\Sigma'$ is moving with uniform velocity $v$ relative to $\Sigma$. The particle is at rest in $\Sigma'$. Both reference frames have common axes $x$ and $x'$. When doing a certain calculation in both reference frames, which one of the obtained results is considered correct? Are they considered both correct or the one obtained by an observer in $\Sigma'$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both correct. You can do physics in any inertial frame you want. (In fact, you can do it in *non*-inertial frames too, but it’s more complicated.) That’s basically what “relativity” means.

One thing worth mentioning is that not *all* physical quantities are relative, i.e., dependent on which reference frame you measure them in. There are lots of *absolute* quantities that are independent of reference frame. These are the Lorentz *scalars*. For example, the energy and the momentum of a particle are frame-dependent, but the invariant mass is frame-independent.

Comment: But we are obtaining two different results when applying Lorentz transformations! How come both are correct?

Comment: Because an observer at rest in one frame measures one result, and an observer in the other frame measures the other. Did you ever learn about *Galilean* transformations?

Comment: If I am standing on the street and you are driving by in a car, and we both observe a bicyclist, isn’t it obvious that the bicyclist has a different velocity relative to you than relative to me?

Comment: So we are both correct in these two cases. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a famous question about a proton crossing the milky-way galaxy. From $\Sigma'$ reference frame, the time it takes the proton to cross the galaxy is $296$ s while $3.15\times10^12$ s in $\Sigma$. How can we explain this? I am trying to visualize time dilation, but I am finding difficulties in this!

Comment: Visualizing time dilation is a separate question.

Comment: OK thank you... I will ask this in a separate question and provide more details on it.

Comment: This question is related to this post. If both observers are correct, why the calculations done in the moving reference frame is called proper time and proper length? So I guess the word 'proper' has nothing to do with whom is correct!

Comment: “Proper” doesn’t mean “correct”; it means “self”. Time measured by your watch is your proper time. Time measured by a watch of someone else who is zooming by in a spaceship is their proper time but not yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96951/discussion-between-naps-and-g-smith).